# Геометрическая вероятность

Tags: python, математика, теория-вероятностей

Есть **задание**: От станции метро до института ходит маршрутка.
Каждое утро в интервал времени с 8:30 до 8:45 водитель
маршрутки подъезжает к остановке, в течение 2-х минут
производит посадку и следует по маршруту. Студент Умников в
тот же интервал времени выходит из метро, ждет маршрутку в
течение 5 минут и, если маршрутки нет, идет в институт пешком.
Какова вероятность того, что сегодня Умников приехал в
институт на маршрутке?
Есть **стандартный метод решения**: [image]

Решил **проверить на компьютере**:

```py
import random as r
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

counter = 0
N = []
for ind in range(100000):
    a_begin = r.random()*(15-2)
    a_end   = a_begin + 2

    b_begin = r.random()*(15-5)
    b_end   = b_begin + 5

    check1 = a_end >= b_begin
    check2 = b_end >= a_begin

    if check1 and check2:
        counter += 1
    N.append(counter / (ind+1))

print(counter / 100000)

X = np.arange(1, 100001)
plt.plot(X[1000:], N[1000:])
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, 0.53, 0.01))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Вот что **получилось**:
[image]

Не могу понять **почему** числа расходятся, **помогите** разобраться.

Comment: Ну начнём с того, что твой "стандартный метод решения" допускает прибытие маршрутки в 8:28...

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, решение на python предполагает, что концы интервалов не могут выходит за 15 минут, а в задаче об этом не говорится. Стандартный метод даёт верное решение.

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду под стандартный метод решения? И при чем тут python!? Эту задачу разве нельзя решить используя другой ЯП?